# Display of an icon in a program compiled with GluonFx

Tags: javafx, icons, gluonfx

I compiled my JavaFx program with gluonFx as a native Windows image and everything works fine except that the program icon does not appear when the file name is displayed in the Windows explorer, while it is displayed when the program is running.
How to make the icon appear next to the program name?

Comment: You are running into this issue: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/298.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the application icon to src/windows/assets/icon.ico and run "mvn gluonfx:build" you will see that exe has the icon in windows. output looks like below in my win 11

[image: ico used in exe from gluonfx]

working code [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/)